# Ubuntu - missing operating system

Tags: ubuntu

I had a fully working Ubuntu system which I wanted to resize in order to be able to install Windows. Using Live CD I managed to resize the primary dev/sda1 and create space for windows. Once I installed Windows I've seen that the system was not letting me to choose the OS at startup. I re-opened the Live CD, moved the boot flag from Window's partition to dev/sda1 and here I am: Missing operating system.

I believe this is a problem concerning grub but I don't have the slightest of what to do and where to look. I'd appreciate help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may want to check [this official page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows). The documentation is pretty easy to follow.

In any case, if the link dies, I describe the procedures to recover the grub settings.

```
 1. Login to Ubuntu using Live CD. 
 2. Open a new terminal (should be shift+alt+t).
 3. Add this repository: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
 4. Install boot-repair: sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
 5. Run it and click recommended settings. Wait a few seconds and when it tells you to do so reboot the computer. You should be done.
```

Let us know if this solves your problem!

Comment: Sir, that totally resolved my problem... Thank you a million times.

Comment: The current session is in BIOS-compatibility mode. Please disable BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode in your UEFI firmware, and use this software from a live-CD (or live-USB) that is compatible with UEFI booting mode. For example, use a live-USB of Boot-Repair-Disk-64bit. 

Whatever it means…

Answer (score 2):

You should always install windows before linux to avoid such boot loader problems :) .

I can appreciate [Rescatux](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/). If you follow the instructions on their [Wiki](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/wizard-restore-grub-with-rescatux/) you can easily rescue/rebuild your grub. Let us know if you have problems while restoring your boot loader :)

Comment: thank you so much, I'll look into that and will let you know!